# Why the type of class property is not expected when it assigned by method defined in super class?

Tags: typescript, class, extends

Thanks [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) and [pac0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479251/pac0) for your guide and patience. I'm sorry for the indistinct question. I really want to solve this problem quickly. After realizing it, I edited the question.

There is a superclass:

```
class Bar<S = {}, Store = {}> {
  state?: S
  store?: Store
  getInitialState(initialState: S) {
    return {
      ...initialState,
      b: 'bar'
    }
  }
}
```

There is a method `getInitialState` in this class. it should accept an object and return a new object with a new property `b`. When I extends it like this:

```
class Baz extends Bar {
  state = initialState
  store = this.getInitialState(initialState)
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
```

`store` will be assigned with the return value of `getInitialState` passing the `initialState`. So the expected type of store is like:

```
{
  a: string,
  b: string
}
```

but in reality it is:

```
{
  b: string;
}
```

So why it behavior like it and how should I do to get what I want?

Whole demo: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMCGNUF44DeAUHHJgPwBccAzjFAJYB2A5kQL5FEDGETdcZgxgNMAGwzZg1STjj5ipTNQDkAI0wAvFRy7cxmGjTgAhTFAA8aeYXYAadDGh5bAPkIlaWHFXSe6zr4Yzp4swDAAkkzCohLewAAUQiListLoAJQepKRQ4QCuUEzZOaQAdBXJsWl2nqVqqhpQOqWcpJycPAZGplpwoDhMACbGZlAldFI2Vanx-k55NjAAFgw0ZWGR0SlxUknb1fEZnrz89PncCwlZijk0+ShQ154dXGLhcBqaNkzAAO69TTPL5lAJ5IgAeghHihOQaXkYrAA3JDoZxYaAUJdgENUTDoUpqHRESxarDSPDicw2LD2EA)

Comment: The playground link is useful, but please include the relevant code in the question itself (see : [mcve])

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  The issue is likely that `Bar` with no generics evaluates to the default `Bar<{}, {}>`; it is not inferred.  If you want to see `a`, you need something like `class Baz extends Bar<State>` instead of `class Baz extends Bar`.  If you edit this question to conform to SO standards I'd be happy to make a full answer.  Good luck!